# How to stop the music from playing?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, switch-statement, media-player

My code here involves two radio buttons. When the "Play Music" button is clicked the music plays. When the "Stop Music" is clicked the music will not stop. How would I fix this? What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked (View view) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music);

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.play_music :
                if (checked) {
                    player.start();
                    playMusic.setEnabled(false);
                    stopMusic.setEnabled(true);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.stop_music :
                if (checked) {
                    if (player.isPlaying()) {
                        player.pause();
                        player.stop();
                        player.release();
                    }
                    playMusic.setEnabled(true);
                    stopMusic.setEnabled(false);
                }
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe just do player = new MediaPlayer(); instead of .create?

Comment: Why are you creating a new music player for the resource? How should the old player stop if you create new one and stop him instead? Try calling `player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music);` only once in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: How would I define the file to play then?